# how can i use the List View and what is an Array adapter? purpose of an Array adapter?

Tags: android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Can anybody explain me **clearly** about how can i use the `ListView` and what is an `ArrayAdapter`? purpose of an `ArrayAdapter`?

Explain me clearly  because am a new one to android. And have read
[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

But the concepts are going in depth.

So, am in need to know the concepts with **short and clear**.

Comment: Reading the API reference is usually not the best way to learn about using the API - unless it contains examples and guides. Try searching for tutorials about `android` and `arrayadapter` and you will find some.

Answer (score 0):

An array adapter is the adapter by which the listview is built. You can use Android's default adapter or create a new one if you wish.

The following tutorial should help you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Ya i have tried. now i came to know something about the concepts. thank u @mlaferla